# Image on ActionLink with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button at the moment, rendered in my MVC application as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteTransfer", "Transaction", new { transferId = (Model.Id) }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger", @onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Transfer?')" })
```

I want to use the Twitter Bootstrap classes to add an icon. However, for that the code would look like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-white icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
```

How can I apply this in my ActionLink? It has an Image (i) embedded in the button.

Comment: Look how create your custom html helper which generate html like you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
      <a class="btn btn-danger" 
           href="@Url.Action("DeleteTransfer", "Transaction", new { transferId = (Model.Id) })"   
           onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Transfer?');"
           >
          <i class="icon-white icon-trash">Delete</i>
      </a>
```

According your routes, it's possible you need:

```
@Url.Action("DeleteTransfer", "Transaction", new { transferId = (Model.Id) }, null)
```

Comment: This isn't really a good answer to the question because you did not put the image on the ActionLink, you just created a hyperlink.

Answer (score -1):

According to the bootstrap documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples) glyphicons might be the way to go.  Here is an example of putting an icon on a button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
</button>
```

Since `ActionLink()` is an htmlHelper extension that returns an "a" element, i.e., `<a>...</a>`, I believe the extension needs to be overridden.

I tried the following, but it resulted in the glyphicon being above the "a" element:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteTransfer")
```

I also tried putting the `ActionLink()` inside the `<span></span>` with the same results. I tried using css with `text-wrap: none;` and `white-space: nowrap;` but that didn't work either.

So I believe the answer is the extension needs to be overridden to accept another parameter for the glyphicon. Unless, someone can show a trick to make it stop wrapping.